# Using rails 4.1.4 - stuck on 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install ruby version 4.1.4. I'm keeping it in specific gem sets

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1.4 --create
gem install rails --version=4.1.4
bundle install
rails -v
```

And I always get back 3.2.9. If I run rails -v before bundle install, I get

> Could not find proper version of railties (3.2.9) in any of the
>   sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

When I run bundle install, I notice the version of rails is 3.2.9. Is there a simple fix for this.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Installing activesupport 3.2.9
Installing builder 3.0.4
Installing activemodel 3.2.9
Using erubis 2.7.0
Installing journey 1.0.4
Installing rack 1.4.5
Installing rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Installing sprockets 2.2.2
Installing actionpack 3.2.9
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Installing mail 2.4.4
Installing actionmailer 3.2.9
Installing arel 3.0.3
Installing tzinfo 0.3.40
Installing activerecord 3.2.9
Installing activeresource 3.2.9
Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.1
Installing execjs 2.2.1
Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using json 1.8.1
Installing rdoc 3.12.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Installing railties 3.2.9
Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2
Installing jquery-rails 3.1.1
Using bundler 1.6.5
Installing rails 3.2.9
Installing sass 3.3.11
Installing sass-rails 3.2.6
Installing sqlite3 1.3.9
Installing strong_parameters 0.2.3
Installing uglifier 2.5.3
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
```

Any ideas how to get 4.1.4?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, prefix commands with `bundle exec` where appropriate.

Secondly, have you tried `bundle update rails`? It could be your Gemfile.lock that's the problem...

Comment: so run bundle exec install instead? I immediately get "install: missing file operand
Try 'install --help' for more information.".

Comment: fixed it... was inside a working directory for a previous rails project configured for 3.2.9

Comment: So it probably was the Gemfile.lock from that project. `bundle exec install ...` will try to run the `install` shell command. `bundle exec gem install rails` will run `gem install rails` in the context of the bundle. Simples.